# string Comparer unexpected results - wrong ordering?

Tags: c#, string, linq, sorting

Consider the following list of two string elements, sorting it with Sort() or ordering with linq .OrderBy() gives an unexpected result, `a.1.10-a-` being the first element in the newly ordered list.

```
var list = new List<string> 
    {
        "a.1.1-a-",  
        "a.1.10-a-", 
    };
    list.Sort();
    foreach(var l in list)
        Console.WriteLine(l);
    foreach(var l in list.OrderBy(x=>x))
        Console.WriteLine(l);
```

Actual results:

```
a.1.10-a-
a.1.1-a-
------
a.1.10-a-
a.1.1-a-
```

However, removing the letter `a` from each of the elements, the output changes to:

```
a.1.1--
a.1.10--
------
a.1.1--
a.1.10--
```

I've reproduced this in https://dotnetfiddle.net/NBF3Pf

But, copying the same code in https://try.dot.net/ gives the expected results with and without the letter `a` included towards the end of the two strings.

I have tried casting each of the strings to a list of char then to list of ints. The two lists are identical until the `0` which has the ASCII code of 48 and the `-` which has a ASCII code of 45.
48 is greater than 45, but still the sorting places the element `a.1.10-a-` first.

EDIT: The same results are happening by using `list.Sort(StringComparer.InvariantCulture);`

Could anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: Wait, your question isn't about the difference in `OrderBy()` vs `Sort()`, is it? Both ways of sorting have the same output. The question is why the default string comparer (which both sorting algorithms use) sorts this way. Can you [edit] your question to remove this confusion? Then I can unmark as duplicate.

Comment: .NET offloads string comparison to the runtime, which (on Windows) offloads it to Windows APIs. This behavior is well documented on MSDN and in duplicate questions I can't find right now.

Comment: You need a custom sort the splits the fields and converts the digits to integers.

Answer (score 0):

The default StringComparer depends on your current culture, so can give different results on different machines.  Try specifying the culture explicitly to get consistent results:

```
    list.Sort(StringComparer.InvariantCulture);
    foreach(var l in list)
        Console.WriteLine(l);
    Console.WriteLine();

    foreach(var aa in list.OrderBy(x=>x, StringComparer.InvariantCulture))
        Console.WriteLine(aa);
```

You could consider using `StringComparer.Ordinal`, depending on what result you want.  I suspect your current culture may be using [CultureInfo.StringSort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.compareoptions?view=netframework-4.7.2). which:

> Indicates that the string comparison must use the string sort algorithm. In a string sort, the hyphen and the apostrophe, as well as other nonalphanumeric symbols, come before alphanumeric characters

Comment: Just tried with `StringComparer.InvariantCulture`, but I get the same results ..

Comment: @StefanKovacs - your DotNetFiddle uses `StringComparer.InvariantCulture` for the `Sort` method, but not for the `OrderBy` method.

Comment: my question was about why adding or removing an `a` after the second to last `-` in my inputs would change the result.

Comment: @StefanKovacs - I suspect the string sort algorithm is being used and is treating hyphens as something akin to word separators.  But it looks like you want `StringComparer.Ordinal` as I already mentioned.